# A good book on humankind’s understanding of primes?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

I might be interested in a good book on what humankind knows about primes as of now, preferably put into historical context.

It should rather be something about the big picture than a comprehensive collection of known results. It should should give a rough outline of what questions have been followed for what reasons and what progress has been made on them.

The level should be somewhere in between undegraduate–graduate. I’m not afraid of seeing algebraic or analytic number theory showing up, as long as conceptual introductions and references are given.

Can anyone recommend something like that?

Comment: "I might be interested in a good book..." well I can assure you primes are very interesting even to non-mathmaticians. I hope you get a good reference.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend reading "Prime Obsession" by John Derbyshire. Although the book is centered around the Riemann Hypothesis, it clearly explains the steps taken prior to it and how we have come to where we are now in order for the reader to gain an understanding of the history of primes. The book is split into two main sections. The even chapters provide historical background, and the odd chapters go more into detail with the math. Derbyshire provides an understandable and thorough explanation of primes.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. The book seems to be on freshman level, though, and only covers the Riemann hypothesis as you already stated. Anyway, thanks for bringing it up!